# how to access properties of dynamically created user controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net

It has been a while that I have not coded so I was trying to get the properties from usercontrols that have been added dynamically.

I have created this code but would like to know if this is a good way or is there another better way of find out the added usercontrols?

```
if (PlaceHolder1.HasControls())
{
    foreach (Control uc in PlaceHolder1.Controls)
    {
        if (uc.GetType().Name.ToLower() == "spinner_ascx")
        {
            Label1.Text += ((Spinner)c).Name + "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just in case, do you add runat="server" attribute to the dymnamically created elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to compare the name if you already know the type of the control:

```
if (PlaceHolder1.HasControls())
{
    foreach (Control uc in PlaceHolder1.Controls)
    {
        if (uc is Spinner)
        {
            Label1.Text += ((Spinner)uc).Name + "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

But yes, if you want to access `Name` and Name is only a property on the `Spinner` class, you need to cast it to the appropriate object.

If you created these user controls, a good idea would be to make sure they all inherit from a base class, e.g.

```
public abstract class MyControl : UserControl {
   public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Spinner : MyControl {

}
```

That way, you don't need to test for each UserControl you want, just the parent class:

```
if(uc is MyControl) {
  Label1.Text += ((MyControl)uc).Name + "<br />";
}
```